# QEMU Driver error : monitor socket did not show up: No such file or directory

Tags: python, qemu, kvm, suse, libvirt

I have a problem when I try to start a VM via libvirt API from a python script. The problem appears from time to time but in the most of the times it works fine

```
libvirt: QEMU Driver error : monitor socket did not show up: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/bbsc/env/bcba", line 495, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/bbsc/env/bcba", line 487, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/bbsc/env/bcba", line 163, in main_cba_restore
    host.start_nodes()
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/bbsc/env/lib/bcba.py", line 300, in start_nodes
    node.start()
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/bbsc/env/lib/bcba.py", line 728, in start
    dom0.create()
  File "/tmp/xjavisn/pyenv_bbsc/versions/py_master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 826, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: monitor socket did not show up: No such file or directory
```

In the VM definition the emulator label contains

```
<emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
```

The hypervisor is:

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 0
```

And the guest:

```
cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```

The versions that I'm using are:

```
virsh # version
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.5
Using library: libvirt 1.2.5
Using API: QEMU 1.2.5
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.0.2
```

Some tasks that I've made
- I've checked the logs in host and guest but there are not errors there. All seem normal
- I modified /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf setting root in user and group section
- qemu and root user are members of libvirt group

Any idea that what is happening?

Best regards
Javi

Answer (score 0):

From the fedora documentation: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/App_Domain_Monitor_Socket.html

To understand the error details, examine the guest log: /var/log/libvirt/qemu/name_of_guest.log

Are you see some errors in this log file?

Comment: Hi!. Thanks for the reply. I don't seee any error message in the guest log file. I only see the regular start/shutdown messages from previous executions.
The problem in the link attached is diferent because there the error message is: "monitor socket did not show up.: Connection refused" and my error is "monitor socket did not show up: No such file or directory"